# Data annotation trigger validation on Get method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have this viewmodel

```
public class ProductViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
       public ProductViewModel()
       {
           Categories = new List<Categorie>
       }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
       public int Code{ get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
       public string Description{ get; set; }

       [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
       public int CategorieId { get; set; }

       public List<Categorie> Categories
}
```

My controller like this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel model)
{
     model.Categories = //method to populate the list
     return View(model);
}
```

The problem is, as soon as the view is exhibited, the validation is fired.

Why this is happening?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Update

The view is like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form" }))
{


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Code" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Code*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Code, new { @class = "form-control"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Desc*</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = "50" })
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Categorie*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategorieId, Model.Categories, "Choose...", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Add the code of your view too, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "validation is fired"?

Comment: The fields are already displayed as not valid (in red), although I had not yet entered or submitted any information at all on them.

Comment: Do you have client validation turned on? If yes, then show the full code for the view.

Comment: The code you have show us will **not** result in validation errors. Possible reasons it might happen is if your method was `public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel model)` or you have some javascript causing validation to fire when the page is first loaded

Comment: You're rigth, Stephen. The method is public ActionResult Create(ProductViewModel model). Sorry for my mistake. I'll correct it on the question.

But, this is a problem? In some places I have to call this action passing Route Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You GET method has a parameter for your model, which means that the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes and instance of the model and sets its properties based on the route values. Since your not passing any values, all the property values are `null` because they all have the `[Required]` attribute, validation fails and `ModelState` errors are added which is why the errors are displayed when the view is first rendered.

You should not use a model as the parameter in a GET method. Apart from the ugly query string it creates, binding will fail for all properties which are complex objects and collections (look at you query string - it includes `&Categories=System.Collections.Generic.List<Categorie>` which of course fails and property `Categories` will be the default empty collection). In addition, you could easily exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

If you need to pass values to the GET method, for example a value for `Code`, then you method should be

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int code)
{
    ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel
    {
        Code = code,
        Categories = //method to populate the list
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: @ErikPhilips, Well spotted (yes for a collection it will be a default empty collection)

Comment: And `int` will be `0` just for the sake of completeness.